# How to use exclusive locks in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, session, locking

I'm trying to implement my own version of session handler using MySQL in PHP. My version differs from existing ones (like Zend's) in that mine is namespaced and each namespace is stored and locked separately. Here's the scenario that should be implemented in code:

1. Acquire an exclusive lock for SID+NS
2. Read SID+NS's data
3. ... request takes its course ...
4. Write SID+NS's data back into db
5. Release the lock

**SID**: session id - **NS**: namespace

Now the question that arises is:

### How to use exclusive locks in MySQL?

There are a number of issues that one needs to keep in mind before answering this question:

1. There are arbitrary number of namespaces in each session.
2. One single request might need to hold more than one ex-locks (one request might need to work on more than one namespace at a time).
3. Locks need to be implemented using MySQL's internal mechanism. Implementing my own application-level ex-locks could be pretty simple. But then you have to implement queues and semaphores to mimic the same behavior MySQL is giving us which makes it really hard. What I'm saying is that I want my code to work on most of the machines without going through heavy changes and I'm not willing to implement a polling system as it is a waste of system's resources and time. If it is implemented using MySQL locks, when conflict happens the code will freeze without wasting CPU time or any resources.
4. Keep in mind that not always a record exists for SID+NS. There are first timer requests which have to insert a record for SID+NS before they can lock it.

**IMPORTANT:** My question is not how to use MySQL locks in general. I've read all the MySQL documents on how to do so. My question comes with some specific scenario which to my eyes makes it impossible to implement. That's why I've asked it here, to make sure if I'm missing anything or not.

PS. This is for [an open source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pome-framework/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so everyone know, I managed to implement this in the mentioned project. So if anyone's interested he/she can find it there.